# Why does my error handling fail with fs.readFileSync()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

If I read a JSON file by just `fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8')` it works, but when I add error handling, I get `undefined`.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let ruleTemplate;
fs.readFileSync('cmdCreateRule.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    ruleTemplate = JSON.parse(data);
  };
});
console.log(ruleTempate);
```

## Question

Can anyone see why `ruleTemplate` becomes `undefined`?

Comment: You should **not** supply a callback when calling `somethingSync()`. It will throw an error if there is a problem even without the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Quentin said, this is a synchronous function, so it does not get a callback as parameter, try this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let ruleTemplate;
try {
  fs.readFileSync('cmdCreateRule.json', 'utf8');
  ruleTemplate = JSON.parse(data);
}
catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
console.log(ruleTempate);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) does **not** accept a callback function. It only accepts two arguments. The third argument (where you are passing your function which assigns a value to `ruleTemplate`) is ignored.

`readFileSync`  **returns** a string or buffer.